# jQueryUI accordion expanded on load

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have an accordion created and when I load the page it shows all content for a second. When finish loading the page, the accordion collapse as intended.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion_rel" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
        active: false
      });
      });
</script>

<div id="accordion_rel">
  <h3>
    Related Articles
  </h3>
  <div>
    <ul class="side-expand">
      {% for cur in topic.articles %}
      <li>
        <a class="{% if article.id == cur.id %}active{% else %}inactive{% endif %}" href='{{ cur.public_url }}'>
          {{ cur.subject_plain | clip:35 }}
        </a>
      </li>
      {% endfor %}     
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the script in the page?

Comment: in the header section

Comment: Then it's trying to run before the Accordion has been added to the DOM so it probably won't work properly. What happens is you put it at the end?

Comment: The problem seems to be around timing, because Grasper said that the behaviour is correct, the problem is just during page loading, where the items are visible, am I right?

Comment: I have no access to that script otherwise I would move it.

Comment: See the docs...the script should be at the end of the page - http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @NicolasR, looks like the default is display:block but when it finishes loading it realizes it needs to hide it.

Comment: @Paulie_D that is not helping..

Comment: @Grasper, yes the script that applies accordion properties is executing "too late". But it is its normal behaviour, you may have slow treatments before...
Maybe you can try to hide your div and show it just before or after the accordion()

Comment: perfect, that worked! Adding inline style of display:none on the first div did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding inline style in the first div did the trick!

```
   <div id="accordion_rel">
      <h3>
        Related Articles
      </h3>
      <div style="display:none">
```

Comment: Thanks, :-), please up-vote so I get some points because I can't comment on peoples questions...